# Laravel 5.5 Cookie doesn't store

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I want to store a custom cookie in user browser and in a register form.
I would create an affiliate system.

I test the basic cmd with this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?ref=159f7172ac1d34
```

In my controller

```
    $ref = $request->query('ref');

    $cookie = Cookie('referral', $ref , 60);

    dd($cookie);
```

The dump of cookie created works perfect. cookie name, value, expire...
But nothing is save into user browser. I have used firefox developpment web to check all cookies in browsers. [image: see this image: cookie is missing in browser]

**Browser doesnt store cookie. Why?**

Nb: I have used also this package https://github.com/codezero-be/cookie but its the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you follow Laravel's documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#cookies

Answer (score 5):

**ok I found Solution**

```
$cookie = Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('CookieName', 'CookieValue', 60));
```

[image: Cookie is store]